# FPV lag on visuo xs812

Tags: first-person-view

I have a visuo xs812 but with a very slow lag. I know that for many people this is a problem, does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some information [here](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3113531-VISUO-XS812-GPS-5G-WiFi-FPV-w-2MP-5MP-HD-Camera-RC-Drone-review-%2A%2AOwners-Thread%2A%2A/page7) which may be helpful to read through. They mentioned the issue of video lag and seemed to find a few potential solutions which were: to use a wifi extender, use a different app (mentioned in the link) to connect to the drone, or adjust settings of your phone like screen resolution and processor power if possible.

As I don't own this drone, I'm not sure that these solutions will fix the issue. But if the video lag persists, just know that you really can't expect very low-latency video from a drone this price.